# Users reporting WPF controls with locked values; how could this happen?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a relatively simple program that I have created using WPF and the .NET 4.0 Client Profile. I used an MVVM approach, where I have views with minimal code-behind which bind to properties on the corresponding view-models; those properties then access the model as necessary. The GUI contains checkboxes, sliders, and other controls as necessary. The sliders are set to have a minimum value of 0, a maximum value of 1, a large change of 0.1, and a small change of 0.05. It all works fine for me and most people.

Unfortunately, several users have reported some very strange issues. They report that the sliders are locked to a value of 0 or 1, and that the values cannot be changed. Normally, the sliders have a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 1, so the values are potentially correct (although they most likely should actually be showing values of 0.5 or so), but they definitely should be adjustable! However, I am not setting IsSnapToTickEnabled; it is left at its default value of false. The sliders are binding to decimal properties on the view-models. I have tried asking these users for more information, but it is unfortunately difficult to get into contact with them, so I am trying to solve it on my own.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit. I have tried experimenting by changing the view-model so that a slider binds to a value lower than its minimum or higher than its maximum, and in these cases the slider handles it fine by simply showing the minimum or maximum and allowing changes. I have tried experimenting by changing the view-model so that a slider binds to a property which throws an exception, and in this case the slider handles it fine by showing the minimum value and allowing changes. This suggests to me that the binding (and therefore, view-model and model) is not the problem, and so the issue is somewhere on the view side of things. I thought that it may be a problem with the style not getting applied, but even an unstyled slider works fine and allows changes normally.

No matter what I do I cannot reproduce the issues that these people are reporting! Therefore, I have come to you for help. **Can you think of any ideas of what could be causing this?** I'm not doing anything unusual as far as I know. I'm just using an ordinary WPF Slider control and binding to a decimal property!

I do know that at least one user who is getting these issues is using the classic theme, and I am forcing the Aero theme in my program, if this is of any relevance.

Here is some example code, but I do not think it will be very helpful...

Slider binding:

```
public decimal TestBinding {
    get { return this.Model.Test; }
    set {
        if (this.Model.Test == value) return;
        this.Model.Test = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("TestBinding");
    }
}
```

Slider control:

```
<Slider Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Value="{Binding TestBinding}"
        Style="{StaticResource Slider0to1}" />
```

Slider style:

```
<Style TargetType="Slider" BasedOn="{Utilities:StaticApplicationResource {x:Type Slider}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="AutoToolTipPlacement" Value="TopLeft" />
    <Setter Property="AutoToolTipPrecision" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Slider0to1" TargetType="Slider" BasedOn="{Utilities:StaticApplicationResource {x:Type Slider}}">
    <Setter Property="AutoToolTipPrecision" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="TickFrequency" Value="0.1" />
    <Setter Property="SmallChange" Value="0.05" />
    <Setter Property="LargeChange" Value="0.1" />
</Style>
```

StaticApplicationResource markup extension:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class StaticApplicationResource : MarkupExtension {

    public StaticApplicationResource(object resourceKey) {
        this.ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("resourceKey")]
    public object ResourceKey { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        if (this.ResourceKey == null) return null;
        return Application.Current.TryFindResource(this.ResourceKey);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do following things to gather some more information,

1. Your report must include operating system.
2. Version and screen size.
3. DPI information, most users set high font size, this probably will change dpi to little bit causing controls to render little differently.
4. WPF version, and also check default dependency property values. You may assume that you have set ticks to false but it may be true by default, or if your xaml is running within some other app and resources might set it to true.
5. Users may only use keyboard, and check how keyboard behaves for these controls.
6. Users may double click, lots of users have habit of double clicking everything (buttons, links)
7. In smaller screen sizes, your controls may be out of views, this is very unlikely as you are receiving max values. Or even on big screens, changing text size may cause layout to hide your controls.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure if the classic theme is the issue, but I've had a LOT of issues with various themes and WPF.  For example, projecting (to an external display) with the Aero theme almost always will eventually cause some quirky behavior with WPF.  I've also had similar issues that seemed to manifest more on certain video cards than others.  And don't get me started on LiveMeeting and WPF  :-)

Definitely test classic theme, and make sure you test on XP too.